# how to manage memory allocation issue in ios ARC proejct

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

i am working on project  in which application memory usage increase continuously[image] even i am on same view and app in idle

i am using ARC, dealloc also not called.
most on my properties are nonatomic and retain.

Comment: Use instruments to find out what is allocated and where from in your code

Comment: In `ARC` you should not use `retain` but `strong`. Also `weak` and not `assign`

Comment: @Wain i am suing it it shows stair like view in instruments under the allocation segment OR feature  of instruments 
but i don't know what to do next it shows me live memory much less than Overall memory

Comment: Your question does not provide enough detail for us to help. However, you should use `Instruments` in `Xcode` to find leaking, over-retained or abandoned memory.  A tutorial for how to do this can be found here:http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/instruments-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-debug-memory-leaks and there are also WWDC videos available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XCode has a built-in memory profiler that can help you with this issue - for a tutorial on how to use it, this might be helpful http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode

Otherwise, if dealloc isn't being called it could be a symptom of a retain cycle (two objects maintain strong references to each other, so they are never deallocated).

Answer (score 0):

You can find fix the Memory Leaks using Analyze option of XCode

Open XCode --- Product --- Analyze

Then you can find the memory allocation issues locaton with blue identification.

You can fix them where you not using any object which are allocated and so on....

Hope it helps you..